# PHP Call to undefined function getLine()

Tags: php, html

This is the error I'm getting(this only shows up when I click the Submit Button):

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getLine() in /var/www/html/php/GoodQuotes/new.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/php/GoodQuotes/new.php on line 17**

Here's Line 17 and I can't seem to find what's wrong with it

```
catch(Throwable $e){
    echo '<div class ="alert alert-danger">'.get_class($e).'on line '.getLine().'in file '.getFile().': '.$e->getMessage().'</div>';
    }
}
```

Below is the whole new.php script

```
<?php include './config.php';?>
<?php include './classes/database.php' ?>
<?php include './classes/Quotes.php'  ?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $text = $_POST['text'] ?: null;
    $creator = $_POST['creator'] ?: 'Unknown';
    
  try{

    $quotesObj = new Quote();
    $quotes = $quotesObj->add($text, $creator);
    } 

  catch(Throwable $e){
    echo '<div class ="alert alert-danger">'.get_class($e).'on line '.getLine().'in file '.getFile().': '.$e->getMessage().'</div>';
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>iQuote</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
      <div class="header clearfix">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills float-right">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="new.php">New Quote</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <h3 class="text-muted">Project name</h3>
      </div>

      
      <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h2>Add Quotes</h2>
          <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Quote Text</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="Quote Text...">
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
              <label>Creator/Author</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="creator" placeholder="Creator name...">
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      

      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; TechRats 2020</p>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"and I can't seem to find what's wrong with it"_ - The error message is very clear. You're trying to call a function called `getLine()` while PHP can't find any function called `getLine()` defined. It's not a native PHP function. Is it a custom function you've made?

Answer (score 0):

Is the function defined in any one of the three files you have included? If not, make sure it is included and pointing correctly.